# Can't provide coordinates of mouse to the `paintComponent()` method located in other class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mousemotionlistener

I am creating a simple program which draws(displays) my image wherever the mouse is located. So the image moves with the mouse arrow.

For this I've created a `JFrame` and I've added `MouseMotionListener` and a `Image`into it by the class named `Frame`. Image is added using `imageComponent` class.

In `MouseMotionListener` I'm getting the mouse coordinate but can't understand how to provide these `x` and `y` coordinates to the `paintComponent` method, and how to repaint it every time when mouse is moved.Here is my code:

`main()` method in `Practice` class:

```
public class Practice {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
          JFrame frame = new Frame();
          frame.setSize(500,500);
          frame.setVisible(true);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      }
  });

} 
}
```

`Frame` class which add listener and `ImageComponent` to the frame.

```
class Frame extends JFrame{
Frame(){
    add(new imageComponent());
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me){
            int x = me.getX();
            int y = me.getY();
            repaint();
        }
    });

}
}
```

`imageComponent` class, which draws image from specified path:

```
class imageComponent extends JComponent{
Image img;
int x,y;
imageComponent(){
    img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Kaushal28\\Desktop\\image.png").getImage();    
}

 public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
}
}
```

In above class I've declared `x` and `y`: the mouse coordinates.
Which I want to get from the listener but can't understand how to do this. Please someone help!

**EDIT:**
if I add `mouseMotionListener` to `imageComponent` then it is giving [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hULmZ.png) errors:

Comment: Beware, mouse coordinates are relative to the component which created them

Comment: [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: @ MadProgrammer okay I understood. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the imageComponent add the mouse listener:

```
class imageComponent extends JComponent {

    Image img;
    int x, y;
    imageComponent() {
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
                x = me.getX();
                y = me.getY();
                repaint();
            }
        });
        img = new ImageIcon(/* path to image */).getImage();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, add the addMouseMotionListener(,..) inside the constructor.